# Capistrano deployment changing directory for migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have a rails app that is not in the root directory of the repository. When it is deployed, some other static files are deployed with it in a parent directory. The structure is something like this:

```
root
-- otherstuff
-- railsapp
```

When I do a deployment with cap deploy:migrations, the Capistrano command that gets executed looks like this, which of course doesn't work:

```
cd /u/apps/minicart/releases/20100717215044; rake RAILS_ENV=staging  db:migrate
```

How do I change this so that it will be:

```
cd /u/apps/minicart/releases/20100717215044/railsapp; rake RAILS_ENV=staging  db:migrate
```

I made it work by adding a task that executes this command after deploy:finalize_update, but I would prefer to use the built in method, plus my hacked version is executed with every deployment.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Tim

Comment: Are static files the same for each deployment?

Comment: No, they change as well, though not as frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be very simple.

I added a deploy namepace to my deploy.rb file and then redefined the migrate method. Now my method runs on cap deploy:migrations.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Migrating the database"
  task :migrate, :roles => :app do
    run <<-CMD
      cd  #{release_path}/minicart; RAILS_ENV=#{stage} rake db:migrate
    CMD
  end
end
```